# Is "webkit" a CSS standard? Such as when used with "@-webkit-keyframes flash{0%,50%,100%{opacity:1} ... ;animation-name:flash}"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to understand where this type of "webkit" content is coming from. I have seen in in multiple CSS files.

Is this an open standard in CSS?

Comment: As it says, it is a vendor prefix and it is **not** a standard.

Comment: A [quick google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=webkit) should help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard.

> WebKit is a HTML/CSS web browser rendering engine for Safari/Chrome.

Other browser's use other rendering engines.

Try to use a clean css, without `-webkit` or `-moz` attributes. Use them only if you very need them, or better even use sass ([compass](http://compass-style.org/) tool) that will add all of them if you will put some css that will need special support for special engine.